# Пример запроса в PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

Не пойму чем отличаются оба запроса, работают одинаково

```
   SELECT * INTO CustCopy FROM Customers;
```

и

```
CREATE TABLE CustCopy AS
SELECT * FROM Customers;
```

Comment: Разница - в бантиках. Второй позволяет уточнить кучу параметров создаваемой таблицы, тогда как первый - нет.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Запросы идентичны. Как прямо указывают [исходный код](https://github.com/postgres/postgres/blob/REL_12_STABLE/src/backend/parser/gram.y#L3993) и [документация](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/sql-selectinto.html):

> SELECT ... INTO is a now-deprecated alternative
>
> The PostgreSQL usage of SELECT INTO to represent table creation is historical. It is best to use CREATE TABLE AS for this purpose in new code.

Стиль `SELECT .. INTO` создания таблиц является историческим и лучше использовать `CREATE TABLE AS`

Comment: *Запросы идентичны.* Нет. Попробуйте воспроизвести эквивалент `CREATE TABLE CustCopy ON COMMIT DELETE ROWS AS SELECT * FROM Customers;` в форме `SELECT INTO`...

Comment: _приведённые_ в вопросе запросы идентичны.